# Show that no non-zero integers satisfy this pair of equations (from Baltic Way 2021)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, solution-verification, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> Show that no non-zero integers $a, b, x, y$ satisfy:
> \begin{cases} ax-by=16. \\ ay+bx=1. \end{cases}

From Baltic-Way 2021.

\begin{align}
&(a+bi)(x+yi)=(ax-by)+i(ay+bx)=16+i. \\
&|(a+bi)(x+yi)|=|16+i|. \\
&\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{257}. \\
&(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)=257. \\
&\therefore a^2+b^2=257, x^2+y^2=1 \text{ or } a^2+b^2=1, x^2+y^2=257.(\because 257: \text{ prime.)} \\
\Rightarrow & \text{No solution.}
\end{align}

Is my solution right?

Comment: P.S. It's related with my previous post, which is $(ac\pm bd)^2+(ad\mp bc)^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$

Comment: Your solution is correct, and very elegant too +1

Comment: Very nice solution. I can't say I would've immediately thought to apply complex numbers here.

Comment: I edited your title to be clearer and more specific.

Comment: From comments on your previous post:  arithmetic of quadratic rings, usual items $x + y \sqrt d$   or $x + y \omega$    where $\omega = \frac{1 + \sqrt d}{2},$ is the first generalization of Gauss composition; the explicit formula is Dirichlet's method.   You might enjoy a book on binary quadratic forms; my favorite is Buell. There is plenty in Dickson's Intro (1929) and other book that willbe fairly easy to find.

Comment: Not as elegant, but you could also square the two equalities, then add them up:
$$\require{cancel}
a^2x^2 + b^2y^2 - \cancel{2abxy} + a^2y^2+b^2x^2 + \cancel{2abxy} = 257 \;\;\iff\;\; (a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)=257
$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your solution is indeed valid, and as FShrike writes in the comments, quite elegant. I'm putting this confirmation in a community wiki answer to mark this question as answered. (I think this is how that works!)