# Continuing with Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity...

Tags: diophantine-equations

Continuing for [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4479936/979028) [Identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4481541/979028)...

> Find non-zero integers $a, b, x, y$ satisfy:
> \begin{cases}
> ax+by=\alpha \\
> ay-bx=\beta \\
> \end{cases}

I also want various solutions to this kind of question. Again, I want many solutions, including solutions that use Brahmagupta-Fibonacci and other solutions.

I want to try with $\alpha=24, \beta=7.$ For my method, the answer to the question is:

> $(a, b, x, y)=(\pm1, \pm2, \pm2, \pm11), (\mp2, \pm1, \mp11, \pm2), (\mp2, \pm11, \mp1, \pm2), (\pm11, \pm2, \pm2, \pm1), (\mp3, \pm4, \mp4, \pm3), (\pm4, \pm3, \pm3, \pm4)$

Comment: We generally ask that users not create new tags without first gauging community interest in the new tag.  There is a [dedicated thread on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34525/) for discussing new tag proposals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{cases}
ax+by=24 \\
ay-bx=7
\end{cases}

Solution with Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity:

> \begin{align}&(ax+by)^2+(ay-bx)^2=(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)=24^2+7^2=625. \\&(a^2+b^2, x^2+y^2)=(5, 125), (25, 25), (125, 5). \\\ \\& \Rightarrow (a, b, x, y)=(\pm1, \pm2, \pm2, \pm11), (\mp2, \pm1, \mp11, \pm2), (\mp2, \pm11, \mp1, \pm2), (\pm11, \pm2, \pm2, \pm1), (\mp3, \pm4, \mp4, \pm3), (\pm4, \pm3, \pm3, \pm4)\end{align}

Comment: What is the point to repeat as an answer something you have already given in your question ? Moreover, this is a particular case that has only an interest if you explain the **method** you have used to obtain these solutions.

Comment: Answers should be answers.  There is no reason to use a "spoiler box" to hide parts of the answer.